# Save formatting of text while saving it in a MySQL DB in PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a textarea where users can enter text and also format it with options like Bold, Italics and Underline. The text is formatted in HTML. So the problem that now arises is how do I store that text in a DB. I can not directly save the HTML as that would create a XSS vulnerability as a user might enters some malicious JS. I am using MySQL and PDO in PHP. I am also limited by the fact that **I can not use a library.**

Comment: you could use http://htmlpurifier.org/. I think it's a good library against XSS, and you can define own filters for allowed tags

Comment: please, post a complete example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look into using [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). It's what SO uses for formatting text/comments, for example.

Comment: @skypjack I have written absolutely no PHP code to save the formatted HTML. The questions asks for a way to do so securely.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, good idea, if it's just about formatting, there is also a good WYSIWYG Editor, so that people on the website doesn't have to learn Markdown: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Comment: If you cannot use an external library, then you're restricted to writing your own HTML parser. All I can say is "good luck".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to the comments, I have to still point you to a good Library like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

**IT IS NOT SAFE** if you don't sanitize your input in a proper way. Don't reinvent the wheel. **USE A Library** for that.

BUT you said:

> I can not use a library.

**UPDATED** my answer:

The least thing you could do is to limit the allowed tags in strip tags and check the attributes, It is still possible to break your markup with this solution, but I think that's OK if you allow HTML.

With [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) you will be able to allow only whitelistet attributes.
You can whitelist your attributes by pushing them to the `$allowedAttributes` array.

So you could simply use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).
Strip tags, strips all html tags, BUT NOT the Tags, you will allow, the second param of striptags is a string where you can define which tags are allowed so you can just allow bold, italic, strong, and so on.

**I still recommend you to use a good library.**

Try this and add your allowed tags to `strip_tags()`:

**example.php**

```
$html = '<h1><img style="float: right;" title="TinyMCE Logo" src="img/tlogo.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="92" height="80" />Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h1>
<p>Feel free to try out the different features that are provided, please note that the <strong>MoxieManager</strong> specific functionality is part of our commercial offering. The demo is to show the integration.</p>
<h2>Got questions or need help?</h2>
<p>If you have questions or need help, feel free to visit our <a href="../forum/index.php">community forum</a>! We also offer Enterprise <a href="../enterprise/support.php">support</a> solutions. Also do not miss out on the <a href="../wiki.php">documentation</a>, its a great resource wiki for understanding how TinyMCE works and integrates.</p>
<h2>Found a bug?</h2>
<p>If you think you have found a bug, you can use the <a href="../develop/bugtracker.php">Bug Tracker</a> to report bugs to the developers.</p>
<p>And here is a simple table for you to play with.</p>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>Product</strong></td>
<td><strong>Cost</strong></td>
<td><strong>Really?</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b onclick="alert(\'hello\');">TinyMCE</b></td>
<td>Free</td>
<td>YES!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Plupload</td>
<td>Free</td>
<td>YES!</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Enjoy our software and create great content!</p>
<p>Oh, and by the way, don\'t forget to check out our other product called <a href="http://www.plupload.com" target="_blank">Plupload</a>, your ultimate upload solution with HTML5 upload support!</p>';

$stripped = strip_tags( $html,"<p><strong><b>" );

// check for attributes
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$loaded = $domDocument->loadHTML( $html ); // will give some warnings on missformatted html

if( !$loaded ) {
    //return some error message
}

$allowedAttributes = array(
    "style",
    "title",
    "alt",
    "widht",
    "height",
    "border"
    // if you are allowing href, please sanitze the href i.e. check against traversal and other stuff like linking to a malicious website
);

foreach( $domDocument->getElementsByTagName( "*" ) as $element ) {
    if( !( $element instanceof DOMElement ) ) continue;
    if( $element->hasAttributes() ) {
        $length = $element->attributes->length;
        foreach( $element->attributes as $attribute ) {
            if( in_array( $attribute->nodeName, $allowedAttributes ) ) continue;
            $removed = $element->removeAttribute( $attribute->nodeName );
        }
    }
}

// not nice, but will remove the html wrapper
# remove <!DOCTYPE
$domDocument->removeChild( $domDocument->doctype );

# remove <html><body></body></html>
$domDocument->replaceChild( $domDocument->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $domDocument->firstChild );

$stripped = $domDocument->saveHTML();

echo $stripped;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!
<p>Feel free to try out the different features that are provided, please note that the <strong>MoxieManager</strong> specific functionality is part of our commercial offering. The demo is to show the integration.</p>
Got questions or need help?
<p>If you have questions or need help, feel free to visit our community forum! We also offer Enterprise support solutions. Also do not miss out on the documentation, its a great resource wiki for understanding how TinyMCE works and integrates.</p>
Found a bug?
<p>If you think you have found a bug, you can use the Bug Tracker to report bugs to the developers.</p>
<p>And here is a simple table for you to play with.</p>



<strong>Product</strong>
<strong>Cost</strong>
<strong>Really?</strong>


<b>TinyMCE<b>
Free
YES!


Plupload
Free
YES!



<p>Enjoy our software and create great content!</p>
<p>Oh, and by the way, don't forget to check out our other product called Plupload, your ultimate upload solution with HTML5 upload support!</p>
```

The example text is taken from the TinyMCE example page ([here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)).

Comment: Beware of the warnings. This can trip over with malformed HTML (you are attempting to sanitise user-data). It also does nothing to sanitise attributes (meaning that you can use `onmouseover="someJavaScript()"` on your `<p>` or `<strong>` elements and still get JavaScript to run).

Comment: Looking back, perhaps this warning wasn't quite strong enough, so for the benefit of the OP and any future readers: **THIS IS NOT SECURE. IF YOU ATTEMPT TO USE THIS TO SANITISE USER-INPUTTED DATA YOU WILL STILL BE VULNERABLE TO XSS ATTACKS**

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP specifically asked for the purposes of sanitisation, so IMO this answer (although accepted) is not really valid.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, ok you're right, that's why my first comment pointet to a good library. BUT I still think with my answer XSS ATTACKS are 95% avoided, if you prove me wrong, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I said If you prove **me** wrong, your example would be stripped by my example in the **answer**